# Can I store a password in a bash script?

Tags: bash, ssh, password, scripts

Is there some way to store (for example hashed etc.) secured password in a script that will be used during connection to server?

Storing password and username as clear text in code for me is quite dangerous. Oh! one more thing - lets assume we can not use RSA keys.

ideas?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/52212/what-is-the-least-insecure-way-to-store-a-password-that-is-used-by-a-script ;)

Comment: thanks :D somehow i did not found this one ;p

Comment: I still had that one bookmarked ;)

Comment: Use DSA keys instead? ;)